# Icon for Representing Elevation

Tags: icons

I am in need of an icon for representing an elevation display, i.e. I have a label containing an elevation in metres, and I need a small (22x22 pixel) icon next to it to indicate thats what it is.

I have tried some things, like a vertical arrow, but none quite look right.

Anyone got any ideas?

I know this isn't strictly a programming question, but it is about a user interface, and therefore software related (i think).

Cheers

**Edit**:

In the end I went for this icon:

[image: Elevation]

It represents it pretty well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UI design, not programming, and solicits subjective recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [this](http://images.google.fr/images?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=jvp&um=1&sa=1&q=elevation&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&start=0&imgtbs=z&imgsz=i&tbo=1)

[image]
 [image]   [image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[alt text http://www.vectorportal.com/symbols/img/opengutter.gif](http://www.vectorportal.com/symbols/img/opengutter.gif)[image][image]

[alt text http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:7DqRw9FL5c9IfM%3Ahttp://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/19/3044b.png](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:7DqRw9FL5c9IfM%3Ahttp://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/19/3044b.png)[image][image]

[alt text http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:jfs_Abjx3BnXEM:http://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/272/50746.png](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:jfs_Abjx3BnXEM:http://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/272/50746.png)[image][alt text http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:L8injTgVVHLlIM%3Ahttp://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/27/61409.png](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:L8injTgVVHLlIM%3Ahttp://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/27/61409.png)

[image][image][image]

[image][image][image]

[image][image][alt text http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:WXHlgHgon09alM:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Japanese_Road_sign_(Descent).svg/470px-Japanese_Road_sign_(Descent).svg.png](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:WXHlgHgon09alM:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Japanese_Road_sign_(Descent).svg/470px-Japanese_Road_sign_(Descent).svg.png)

See also http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/services/publications/fhwaop02084/index.htm

Don't forget about copyrighted

## ©

images

Answer (score 2):

Something like this : (http://www.waymarking.com/images/cat_icons/elevationSigns.gif)

actually 24x24

[image: elevation]

Comment: Nice concept, but the jaggies... *shudder*

Comment: I thought the legend '2100m' made all the difference, but the OP preferred the mountains without an elevation. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an icon form templates using [axialis icon workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/). It is really convenient to use. As I remember there was a template. If no you can ealily import a image and edit or draw a one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a sensible use of an icon; they're OK as visual cues to find something quickly once you've learned to recognize one, but as you have noticed, they suck at conveying actual information. Abbreviated text ("El.") would be more useful if you really lack the space for a full-length text label.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a plane:

[alt text http://www.pekkagaiser.de/stuff/Plane.gif](http://www.pekkagaiser.de/stuff/Plane.gif)

Would need some re-working to look good on 22x22, though.
Plane stolen from [here](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/2695269/2/istockphoto_2695269-aircraft-silhouette-collection-vector-jpg.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-illustration-2695269-aircraft-silhouette-collection-vector-jpg.php&usg=__efMVngCpJBgir_MuAT_TJtQEfAU=&h=380&w=380&sz=36&hl=en&start=44&um=1&tbnid=Aj_J1ia31L444M:&tbnh=123&tbnw=123&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dplane%2Bsilhouette%2Bicon%26ndsp%3D21%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26sa%3DN%26start%3D42%26um%3D1).

Answer (score 0):

bullet_arrow_top from here any good:

http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png

Download the set here:

http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/